# How to set the Predicate for date and time interval in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard and core data.In my core data i have one table with 5 fields startdate, enddate, starttime, and endtime.The values store in these fields are in gmt values.How i will set predicate for check present time is in between startdate and enddate. and starttime and end time

Sample data is given below.

Table A

name | startdate    |   enddate     |  starttime  |  endtime

A  | 31/12/2013   |   31/12/2014  |  5.30       |  17.40

B  | 31/12/2011   |   31/12/2012  |  6.30       |  12.40

c  | 31/12/2011   |   31/12/2015  |  6.30       |  8.40

here all values is in gmt. i need to check the present date(gmt) is within startdate and enddate.here  name 'A' and 'c' is satisfied my condition.if the date is satisfied check current time (gmt) is in-between start time and end time. here 'B' only satisfied this condition.How i write predicate for that

Comment: Describe what data entities you have which have date and time you want to fetch with the predicate.

Comment: DisableR I edited the question please check it

Comment: Describe data types you're using in core data for startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime. E.g. Date, String, Float, etc.

Comment: Disable R I put one more question would you help me for solve this problemhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802117/nspredicate-for-time-interval

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch only the ones between startdate and enddate use something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
predicateWithFormat:@"startdate >= %@ AND enddate <= %@"
, startdate
, enddate];
```

If you want to fetch the one between start and enddate, and between starttime and endtime use something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
predicateWithFormat:@"(startdate >= %@ AND enddate <= %@) AND (starttime >= %@ AND endtime <= %@)"
, startdate
, enddate
, starttime
, endtime];
```

Comment: Do you want only the ones who pass both conditions (between the two dates and between the two times)? It's not very clear what you really want.

Answer (score -1):

Use `TimeInterval`, it would be something like this:

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *endDate =...;

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval currentTimeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSince1970];

BOOL isBetween = currentTimeInterval >= [startDate timeIntervalSince1970] && currentTimeInterval <= [endDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: what is startDate and endDate?

Comment: start and endDate are retrieved somehow by you. As you said that you use core data.

Comment: startDate and endDate are the 2 fields in the table i need to check today is in that interval