# NSPredicate for time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have one table with 4 fields startdate ,enddate, starttime and endtime. I need to set predicate something like

```
if
   startdate<= currentdate and currentdate <= enddate
   if 
      starttime <= currenttime and endtime <= endtime
   else
      starttime <= currenttime and currenttime<= 23.00 or 0.00 <= currentime and currentime <= endtime
```

How i set predicate for this type of condition.Current date and current time is the my system time in gmt.

Comment: Why don't you combine the date and time in a `NSDate` then you can easily write these statements.

Comment: Again you haven't described types of columns in your table. What are types of startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime? String? or Date? Or what?

Comment: @rockones timefileds are stored in string format.

Comment: @Disable R startdate and enddate are date format and starttime and end time are in string format.

Comment: Well if they are string then you will need to convert them to `NSDate` you can **not** compare them if they are strings.

Comment: It will never work since you are using string, which can not be used in the way you want. Convert your data model to use `NSDate` and you are good to go.

Comment: @rckoenes NSPredicate *predTimeSlot = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startdate <= %@) AND (enddate >= %@) AND (Starttime <= %@) AND (Endtime >= %@)",todayDate,todayDate,presentTime,presentTime]; I set one predicate something like that here i got answer if date is in between startdate and enddate  and time is inbetween start time and end time.....(first if condition in my question) I need to set the else condition also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSCompoundPredicate`

Create `NSMutableArray` to hold your predicates with their conditions

```
NSMutableArray *conditions = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Build your conditions and add them to this array

```
[conditions addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startdate <= %@ AND enddate <= %@",[NSDate date],[NSDate date]]];
```

Add as many conditions as you like. Finally build your `NSCompoundPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:conditions];
```

If you have your `startdate` and `enddate` in `NSDate` format you can access it time component as well, there is no need of separate `starttime` and `endtime` just compare the two dates and should be ok.

Comment: I need to compare the time interval also.based one the time i need to fetch the object. if today date is match with date condition i  need to check the current time is within the time interval.if one time interval in my db is 10.20 to 17.50 ..my current time is 12.40 in this condition i got correct value but if the time interval is 12.00 to 7.00 this predicate will become failed. in this situation  i need to divide the time interval in to two...currenttime<= 23.59  or 0.00 <= currenttime

Comment: You have startdate and enddate they are both stored in your CoreData as timestamps which gives you very accurate date and time for each one of them. If you just use the example I gave above you could get very accurate result based on IF current date/time falls between your two dates

Comment: Sorry Panayotov it is not working....empty array will return but i have value in core data

Comment: How you are setting this `startdate` and `enddate` in `CoreData`?
Can you just get all results and print the output for them. I think you have just set the date as 2014/05/21 00:00:00, so when you storing your `NSManagedObject` try setting the time as well as the date and try again

Comment: if condition are true i will this type result from core data fetch request.2013-09-15 16:50:06 +0000....this is the date, 07:16.... time  data